# i dont know how to update and replace image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to replace and update uploaded Image using codeigniter. But I am not sure how to achieve that. Here is my below code -

MY CONTROLLER :

```
 public function updateProccess()
{
    $this->items_model->updateData();
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Update data is success');
    }
    redirect('items');
}
```

AND here's my model to update data

```
public function updateData()
{

    $data = [
        'barcode' => $this->input->post('barcode'),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'categories_id' => $this->input->post('category'),
        'units_id' => $this->input->post('unit'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
        'updated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];
    $this->db->where('items_id', $this->input->post('items_id'));
    $this->db->update('items', $data);
}
```

thank you for your help :)

Comment: How do you create/input the image in the database in the first place?

Comment: my controller : https://wtools.io/paste-code/bz1y and my model : https://wtools.io/paste-code/bz1z

Comment: I am not sure about codeignator, but if you wanna replace image, then you should delete image which is uploaded previously. First check that if that image is available and then delete it. and upload new one.

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data check here

Answer (score 0):

This is my case:

Step 1: First I have checked file is not empty, if file is empty update file will not work, if file is uploaded from html then I have fetched previous record from database in a $row variable (temporary variables).

Step 2: After getting previous data, I have updated data in database i.e. path and name of new file.

Step 3: After that I have verified that user is updating data or inserting new one. If data is to be updated then old image will be deleted.

```
if($_FILES["img"]["name"]!="")
{
    $row=$this->general_model->getSingle("banner", ["id"=>$id]);
    $temp=$_FILES["img"]["name"];
    $temp=explode(".", $temp);
    $ext=end($temp);
    $file_name_temp="banner".time().rand(0,9);
    $file_name=$save["img"]=$file_name_temp.".".$ext;
    $config["file_name"]=$file_name;
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 1024*10;
    enter code here
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('img'))
    {`enter code here`
        $msg=strip_tags($this->upload->display_errors());
        _setFlashSession("msg", "<span class='label label-danger'>$msg</span>");
        redirect("admin/site-configure/banner");
    }

    if($id!="")
    {
        $file="./uploads/".$row["img"];
        unlink($file);
        $file="./webp/".$row["webp"];
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```